# App is getting slow or crash cause I'm making layouts dynamically and setting pictures as their backgrounds

Tags: android, android-layout, android-background

The idea: I've a FAB button in my main activity which creates an alert dialog with edit text asking for a project's name and then creates relative layout and its child a text view, set the relative layout as child to the linear layout and set a picture of size around 300 Kb as background image of relative layout on every press.

The problem: as I'm creating relative layouts and setting pictures as their backgrounds, the dialog is getting delayed after every press and everything is working slow but as I made one change which is to set a background color instead of an image, everything is working just normal. So it's pretty obvious that images were my problem. But it could be my code's problem also. So need some guidance here. Thanks guys in advance.

Below is my Alert Dialog's code:

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.view.Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;

public class CreateProjectAlertDialog extends DialogFragment {

    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    final int[] images = new int[]{R.drawable.background1, R.drawable.background2, R.drawable.background3};

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        final View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_project_alert_dialog_layout, null);
        return builder.setView(root)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.parent);
                        TextView child = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.create_a_project_text);
                        parent.removeView(child);

                        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                        editor = preferences.edit();
                        int i = preferences.getInt("i", 0);
                        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
                        relativeLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), images[i]));
                        if (i == 2) {
                            editor.putInt("i", 0);
                            editor.apply();
                        } else {
                            editor.putInt("i", i + 1);
                            editor.apply();
                        }  

                        int height = 200;
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);
                        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


                        EditText editText = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.project_name);
                        String projectName = editText.getText().toString();

                        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
                        textView.setText(projectName);
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        textView.setTextSize(25);
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        textViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
                        textView.setLayoutParams(textViewLayoutParams);

                        relativeLayout.addView(textView);

                        parent.addView(relativeLayout);

                        View view = new View(getActivity());
                        int viewHeight = 1;
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams viewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, viewHeight);
                        view.setLayoutParams(viewLayoutParams);

                        parent.addView(view);

                        dismiss();
                    }
                }).create();
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't u use glide for setting images

Answer (score -2):

Images can consume a lot of memory footprint.
This what slows down your app.

You didn't provide any crash logs but I assume your crash is OutOfMemeory Exception.

You want to reduce the memory footprint of your image before loading it into the memory. The Android developers site has a really nice, to-the-point article about just that: [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently | Android Developers](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjs9cXRn-LUAhXMiRoKHfj6CvMQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Ftopic%2Fperformance%2Fgraphics%2Fload-bitmap.html&usg=AFQjCNEJjMO72l9CZFDJ7MQ4zQXQqvAgZQ)

Comment: The app was getting crashed when I set a background image for linear layout which gets its children relative layout dynamically

Comment: Please provide the crash log: [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html)